# I'm looking for a suitable synonym to say you need "throw everything you've got" at a problem

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

When to fix a particular problem you need to use many different approaches all at the same time.  What synonym could i use to express this.

Comment: Please provide more context. And please add a sample sentence with a blank showing how you want to use this. In general "throw everything you've got" or "give it everything you've got' works pretty well. Why don't you like those?

Comment: Sorry, I tried everything but the kitchen sink but couldn't come up with an idea for you.

Comment: 'Commit totally' is idiomatic, but doesn't reference the 'attack from all angles' aspect (but then neither, really, does 'throw everything you've got at'). 'Leave no stone unturned' seems to suggest that you try all available approaches, and 'approach/tackle a problem from all sides' certainly does.

Comment: If the problem can be solved with money, you'd be willing to ***break the bank*** to solve it. [Reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+the+bank)

Comment: If it's a disorganised/last ditch effort perhaps you are **Throwing mud at the wall** (to see what sticks)

Comment: Full-court press.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can think of is **pulling out all the stops**.

[Wiki link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull_out_all_the_stops)

> **Etymology**
>
> An allusion to organ stops, which are pulled out to turn on each set of sounds in a pipe organ. When all stops are pulled out, the organ will play all variations of its sounds at once, therefore being as loud as possible.
>
> **Definition**
>
> *(idiomatic) To reserve or hold back nothing.*
>
> **Example**
>
> They pulled out all the stops for the gala wedding.

In the context of your question, pulling out all stops can be interpreted as "using every skill you've got".

Comment: It was essential to have the organ working by Sunday, so they pulled out all the stops.

Comment: +1 Great answer,  a very suitable idiom and reasonable currency in usage, at least in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a correct word would be *multifaceted*. From MW.

> Having many facets or aspects. *A multifaceted approach to
>   health care*.

Answer (score 1):

### Full spectrum approach

Using many approaches at once can be described as *using the full spectrum*. For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_spectrum_diplomacy):

> Full spectrum diplomacy is an integrated strategy that encompasses all instruments of engagement including traditional diplomacy and public diplomacy.